# NestJs - Access service class in other module (Error: Cannot find module 'src/user/user.service')

Tags: nestjs

In auth module am trying to access userservice class from usermodule, am getting error like cannot find module src/user/user.service
Please find sample code ---

Thanks in advance.

**Auth Module**

```
@Module({
    imports : [UserModule],
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [JwtStrategy, AuthService],
    exports : [JwtStrategy, AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**UserModule**

```
@Module({
    imports : [ MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name : 'User', schema : UserSchema }])],
    controllers: [UserController],
    providers: [UserService],
    exports : [UserService, MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name : 'User', schema : UserSchema }])]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**AppModule**

```
  imports: [
          AuthModule,
          UserModule,
          MongooseModule.forRoot('--',
          )],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to replace src/ with ../ or any relative path that you have with 
navigating to that path, with ./ or ../ it happens a lot when you auto-import
some file. Also, you can export User service in User module, and place it (UserService) in Auth providers without importing whole module.

Comment: Hi Rambabu,please accept the answers, if it works for you. :)